# Does mvn spring-boot:run rebuild the project in Intellij?

Tags: java, spring-boot, build, rebuild

I'm learning about Spring Boot microservices, and I'm using Spring Cloud Gateway and I'm using it as a OAUTH2 client. But I think this is not so important, what exactly does the microservice. I want to ask you if `mvn spring-boot:run` command from Intellij terminal rebuilds the project.

I ask you that because I started all the microservices with `mvn spring-boot:run` command in intellij terminal and when I tried to call a GET request on the Gateway microservice, it didn't work properly. The request should be redirected to the Keycloak authentication server, and it didn't work in this way.

After that I clicked the Build -> Rebuild Project button on Intellij and then I started this microservice again, and this time it worked fine. So, I want to ask you if the `mvn spring-boot:run` command executed on Intellij terminal does `mvn clean install` behind the scenes. And if Build -> Rebuild Project button from Intellij does `mvn clean install` behind the scenes. Thank you! Any feedback will be apreciated.